# Flutter: how to override function

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Basically, I want to override a few props of ancestor `showDialog` function which is located in `packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart`

I want to change `barrierColor` property and remove `SafeArea` widget from showGeneralDialog builder method.

```
//...
Future<T> showDialog<T>({
  @required BuildContext context,
  bool barrierDismissible = true,
  @Deprecated(
    'Instead of using the "child" argument, return the child from a closure '
    'provided to the "builder" argument. This will ensure that the BuildContext '
    'is appropriate for widgets built in the dialog.'
  ) Widget child,
  WidgetBuilder builder,
}) {
  assert(child == null || builder == null);
  assert(debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations(context));

  final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true);
  return showGeneralDialog(
    context: context,
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
      final Widget pageChild = child ?? Builder(builder: builder);
      return SafeArea( // <-- !remove SafeArea widget!
        child: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return theme != null
                ? Theme(data: theme, child: pageChild)
                : pageChild;
          }
        ),
      );
    },
    barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
    barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
    barrierColor: Colors.black54, // <-- !change the color!
    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
    transitionBuilder: _buildMaterialDialogTransitions,
  );
}
```

Is it possible to do in `main.dart` file? If yes could anyone give some example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy/paste that function to your main.dart file, change the name and the barrierColor there and it will work because you can use showGeneralDialog